# Error when trying to generate early bound entity classes using crmserviceutil

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have used crmservicetuil.exe that comes with CRM SDK many a times before for online instance of CRM 2011.

It did work for the plugins and the integration tool for the online instance of CRM that i developed for our client,that is until about a month and a half back (that is when we last deployed our solution).

However I cant figure out what changed on their system, am trying to generate the early bound entity class using the following command(the same which i used earlier and it worked fine)

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://<ORGNAME>.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:Xrm.cs  /username:myid@outlook.com /password:myP@ssword /namespace:Xrm  /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

but there is an error thrown that says,
     exiting the program with exception: The parameter is incorrect.
What could have possibly changed to cause this error? Am still having the login permissions and am able to navigate to the  https://.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc when given the same id and password.

there is only one difference though(may or may not be useful):The last time I used the command, i used my non live id (office-365). Removed the license for that user and added a new one with an outlook(live) id about 2 weeks back.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this posts: [Run the Code Generation Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx#bkmk_RuntheCodeGenerationUtility) or [CrmSvcUtil.exe](http://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/developers-guide/knowledge-base/crmsvcutilexe/): to use Live Id you need to generate and add Device Id and Device Password to yours command string.